# What does the Staking.EraPaid event mean?

Tags: polkadot, staking, events

According to Polkadot's events description page, the [`Staking.EraPaid`](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events/#erapaidu32-u128-u128) event means the following:

> The era payout has been set; the first balance is the validator-payout; the second is the remainder from the maximum amount of reward. [era_index, validator_payout, remainder].

However, I'd like to know for sure if this event means any balance change has just happened.

More specifically, would I be correct if I said that the validator of the current block would receive `validator_payout` as a reward? Or do I have to do some math with  `remainder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validator_payout` is the amount that will be paid to all the validators (and their nominators) after an era (not the payment for one validator for the current block).

The `EraPaid` event is deposited after computing the payout for a particular era with the `end_era` function: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs (this payout is for all validators/their nominators)

the `remainder` is got by substracting the `validator_payout` from `max_payout` in the `era_payout` function:

```
   fn era_payout(
        total_staked: Balance,
        total_issuance: Balance,
        era_duration_millis: u64,
    ) -> (Balance, Balance) {
        let (validator_payout, max_payout) = 
        inflation::compute_total_payout(
            &T::get(),
            total_staked,
            total_issuance,
            // Duration of era; more than u64::MAX is rewarded as u64::MAX.
            era_duration_millis,
        );
        let rest = max_payout.saturating_sub(validator_payout.clone());
        (validator_payout, rest)
    }
```

Comment: so the `Staking.EraPaid` event doesn't mean that a payment is happening, but that it will happen to all validators during this era, correct? Would you know if the payment for each validator can be traced by any event? For example, `Staking.Reward`?

Comment: Correct. the `Staking.EraPaid` event only signifies that the payout for that era has been set. On the other hand, the `Staking.PayoutStarted` event signifies that the payout has started, while the `Staking.Rewarded` event signifies that a nominator has been rewarded with a specific amount.