# How do the Staking Rewards payouts work?

Tags: substrate-node-template, staking

I've added `Staking` to `substrate-node-template` and just explored the feature. I've managed to add validators and nominators and it looks like everything is working well.

One thing I'm not able to figure out is how the rewards are being distributed. I've been watching the events at the end of every era and it looks like only `Staking.EraPaid` is being fired.

From what I understand from the discussion here, [What does the Staking.EraPaid event mean?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/643/what-does-the-staking-erapaid-event-mean) , I should be getting the events `Staking.PayoutStarted` and `Staking.Rewarded` as well.

I guess I'm trying to figure out the following

1. Which pallet is actually distributing the rewards? `pallet_election_provider_multi_phase` or `pallet_staking`
2. Is there anything I need to define for the Payouts to happen?

Comment: pallet-staking is in charge to distributing the awards, and it does so using a staking-reward-curve that's defined in the documentation. As far as Payouts are concerned, an extrinsic needs to be fired before payouts can occur so I am not sure if that is default behaviour because from my experience, I don't remember seeing `EraPaid` at the end of every era.

Comment: @Purple_Turtle I see. I do see the `EraPaid` event at the end of every era though. But, nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, validators are paid proportionally to the amount of era points they have collected. Payments occur at the end of every era.

- [`end_era`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L377) triggers the payout for the finished era.
- [`do_payout_stakers`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a09b82772b0597cdae224f4b124d660dda9e82b/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L94) for checking out how the payment calculation starts so validators get fraction of the era reward that belongs to the validator and which part of the reward goes to its nominators, between other things.
- [`make_payout`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a09b82772b0597cdae224f4b124d660dda9e82b/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L231) where the payments to stakers are done.

If you check those methods you will see that the interesting events to follow, and very well pointed out in the linked discussion are
`PayoutStarted` and `Rewarded`

Now, nominators, as @Purple_Turtle mentions, need to call [`payout_stakers`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a09b82772b0597cdae224f4b124d660dda9e82b/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L1369) so all nominators behind a specific validator get their rewards. This can be called by anyone, and triggers `do_payout_stakers` mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I was using https://polkadot.js.org/apps/ and the balances weren't being updated. We checked it in `substrate-front-end-template` and we could see the payouts.

Comment: Keep in mind that the front_end_template is a very minimal front_end, and you will laverage much more by using polkadot.js apps directly connected to your node